# Scapy isn't outputting any computers connected to network

Tags: python

I'm using Scapy to output all connected computers and VMs connected to network:

```
 from scapy.all import ARP, Ether, srp

 target_ip = '192.168.1.1/24'
 arp = ARP(pdst=target_ip)
 ether = Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')
 packet = ether/arp
 result = srp(packet, timeout=3)[0]
 clients = []
  
 for s, r in result:
    clients.append({'ip': r.psrc, 'mac': r.hwsrc})
      
 for client in clients:
    print(f'{client["ip"]} {client["mac"]}')
```

There are 6 IPs on the network 1 of which is a virtual machine.
Running the script above gives me:

```
Begin emission:
.Finished sending 256 packets.
............
Received 13 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 256 packets
```

As this is a recon part of the whole pentest process it is concerning that
scapy isn't giving me any devices.

Any suggestions ?

**Edit:**

```
(owasp) mark@work:~/owasp$ nmap -n -sV 192.168.1.1/24
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-07-26 18:59 BST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.2
Host is up (0.018s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
23/tcp open  telnet  DD-WRT telnetd (DD-WRT v24-sp2 micro (c) 2009 NewMedia-NET GmbH)
80/tcp open  http    DD-WRT milli_httpd
Service Info: OS: Linux; Device: WAP; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.64
Host is up (0.0075s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     Dropbear sshd 2012.55 (protocol 2.0)
80/tcp open  http    TP-LINK embedded httpd
Service Info: OS: Linux; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.218
Host is up (0.00014s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.1.218 are closed

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (3 hosts up) scanned in 10.61 seconds
```

Comment: Can you see the 6 computers with nmap? Or with ping? Maybe they are configured to not respond.

Comment: P.S. The python code you posted works for me.

Comment: I've added nmap output. It gives me more information. Sadly it's not outputting any vm. The VM is really what I'm after.

Comment: Do you know the IP of the VM? Does it respond to ping from the host? And vice-versa, can you ping the host from the VM?

Comment: I'm pentester student (failing horribly I may add). It's vuln box. So no logins provided and no IP in this case. :)

Comment: The brainpan is on bridged connection. That's all I got.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that your attack VM is not in the same network than your targets. May you confirm this by running "ip a" command ?

What I imagine is that your script is sending ARP packets on a layer 2 network, trying to resolve all IPs broadcasting ARP requests. Your attack machine's network is not the same as your targets one. The router between your machine and your targets drops the ARP  requests, which is an intended behaviour. NMAP works at layer 3 in your case. ARP requests are not originated by your VM but by the last router sitting between it and your targeted network, which correctly resolves.